# Internal scala compilation. Working with interactive.Global

Tags: scala

I am trying to retrieve the AST from scala souce file. I have simplified the code (only relevant code) to following.

```
trait GetAST {
     val settings = new Settings
     val global = new Global(settings, new ConsoleReporter(settings))
     def getSt = "hello" //global.typedTree(src, true)
}
object Tre extends GetAST {
    def main(args:Array[String])
    {
        println(getSt.getClass)
        println("exiting program")
    }
}
```

The above code compiles fine and runs fine. But the problem is the program does not exit. The prompt is not displayed after printing "exiting program". I have to use ^c to exit.
Any idea what the problem might be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe Michael is correct, the compiler uses Threads and therefore the JVM doesn't just exit.

The good news is that `interactive.Global` mixes in `interactive.CompilerControl` trait whose `askShutdown` method you can call at the end of your main to let the program exit.

Comment: That was exactly what I was missing. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing what `Settings`, `Global` and `ConsoleReporter` are nobody can give you an exact answer. I would guess that at least one of them is creating a thread. The JVM waits until all threads are done (or all running are deamon threads). See [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon(boolean)).

I would bet if you comment out the `settings` and `global` lines it will exit as expected.

Comment: Settings, Global and ConsoleReporter are from standard scala compiler.
import scala.tools.nsc.Settings
import scala.tools.nsc.interactive.Global
import scala.tools.nsc.reporters.ConsoleReporter